# Spring boot execute second retry method after first retry method is successful

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry, retrytemplate

I wanted to create two retry methods.
Where in second retry method  is async method. It should be hit only after successful completion of first method.

```
@Retryable(value = { LockedException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))

Public String firstMethod() {    
    return "first";    
}

@Async
@Retryable(value = { LockedException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))    
public String secondMethod() {    
    return "second";    
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Call `firstMethod()` method before `secondMethod()`?

Comment: What if first method fails and is in retry loop . I don't want second method to be executed in that case. Second mthod should only be executed only if successful completion of first method

Comment: What if you call `secondMethod` from `firstMethod`? You would have to move one of the two methods to a different bean though (because of async)